# MySQL thousands of updates, slowing down

Tags: php, mysql

I need to run a PHP loop for a total of 100, 000 times (about 10, 000 each script-run), and each loop has about 5 MySQL UPDATES to it. When I run the loop 50 times, it takes 3 sec. When I run the loop 1000 times, it takes about 1300 sec. As you can see, MySQL is slowing down ALOT with more UPDATEs.

This is an example update:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET `row1`=`row1` +1 WHERE `UniqueValue`='5'");
```

This is generated randomly from PHP, but I can store it in a variable and run it every n loops.

Is there any way to either make MySQL and PHP run at a consistent speed (is PHP storing hidden variables?), or split up the script so they do?

Note: I am running this for a development purposes, not for production, so there will only be 1 computer accessing the data.

Comment: What database type are you running? MyISAM or InnoDB? And if you're using InnoDB, are you using transactions?

Comment: What are the other queries? I'm curious if it's possible to combine them.

Comment: Querying thousands of times in a loop is usually a bad idea.  Consolidate your queries.  Performance will improve dramatically.

Comment: It's pretty much thousands of the same query, just different rows and different UniqueValues.

Comment: You can specify multiple columns to update within an `UPDATE` statement, and use other operators (such as `IN` or `BETWEEN ... AND`) to specify multiple UniqueValues. I'm still curious as to the specific queries, for the same reason. If there are just 5 simple queries in a single loop, that's not much code. Show it to us.

Comment: The query line is: mysql_query("UPDATE Table SET `" . $value[1] . "`=`" . $value[1] . "` +1 WHERE `UniqueValue`='" . $value[0] . "'");
$value[1] might equal 5, and $value[0] might equal "abbaca". They are both randomly generated, and $value[0] is a string which only uses "a", "b", or "c".

Comment: Would there be any conflicks if I do ALL of these steps? (Sorry for asking so much)
-Prepare statements (I'm going to 2 tables, is that ok?)
-disable then re-enable keys
-index UniqueValue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). One of their two main benefits is that repeated queries are more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Using something like this should be loads faster:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET `row1`=`row1` + 1 WHERE `UniqueValue` IN (5, ... 10)");
```

Assuming you've got an index on uniqueValue ofcourse. You can create queries up to 8MB with the default settings but 1MB should be more than enough for now. It will be a huge query but *much* faster.

You could also temporarily disable the index updates entirely, that should make things a bit faster too:

```
ALTER TABLE table DISABLE KEYS;
ALTER TABLE table ENABLE KEYS;
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn the auto_commit off and commit the transaction explicitly after N times (if you are working with InnoDB tables).

Answer (score 0):

Add index on `UniqueValue` and delete index from `row1` and other not used indexses.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from indexing the `row1` and `UniqueValue` fields, also ensure that they are using an numeric datatype like `INTEGER` and remove those singlequotes from the `UniqueValue` in the `WHERE` clause.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET `row1`=`row1` +1 WHERE `UniqueValue`=5");
```

Else MySQL would need to massage it forth and back to/from String which is a performance cost.